# Error in installation of data migration tool for m2

Tags: magento2

I stuck on installation of data migration tool for m2. I am doing this in my localhost. i am using following commands to install data migration tool

```
composer config repositories.data-migration-tool git https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.2
```

I also tried

```
composer config repositories.magento composer https://repo.magento.com
composer require magento/data-migration-tool:2.1.2
```

i tried to resolve this query from searching on google but i didn't get answer
I am getting error Your php version 7.0.0 does not satisfy that requirenent although my php version is 7.0.8. please consider screenshots

Error:
[image]

PHP Version:
[image]

Comment: It requires PHP's Specific `5.6.0 or 7.0.2 or 7.0.6` Version Only Why?

Comment: i have same question :( . even i am not using 7.0.0 still it throws such error everytime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your php version is "too new"

It probably simply that this version hasn't been tested yet - note that it is Magento2 itself, not the data migration tool which has these restrictions.

You have the option to either install an older PHP (if it's your local server might be easier), wait a little, file a bug/question on github - or decide to risk it. 7.0.7 and 7.0.8 seem to only have been fixing bugs, so things could just work. If you're just testing, learning, preparing, you could take the risk.

I checked the bugs filed on github mentioning 7.0.8 and the first few I looked at don't seem to be 7.0.8 specific. But you are taking a risk, and that risk is that you fight days with a bug that turns out to have been 7.0.8...

You would need to edit the composer.json file for magento2:

```
{
"name": "magento/magento2ce",
"description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.2.0-dev",
"license": [
    "OSL-3.0",
    "AFL-3.0"
],
"require": {
"php": "~5.6.5|7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6",
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, i am just learning in local with dummy data so risk is not matter. i will try it in older version of php. i have edited composer.json as you have suggested but not working.
thanks..

Comment: it's probably the fastest. there's enough trial and error with configuration files with the data migration tool without adding more risk

Comment: exactly.. 
i found tool of uber on github. excellent work but i want to use magento's data migration tool so still searching anyway to resolve such errors  thanks :)

Comment: In my first go with the data migration tool - which was 1.9.2 -> 2.1.1 I was pleasantly surprised (only did the data so far). It took a while to edit all the xml files and tell it to ignore all extension added tables and columns, but after that the entire order history, customers, products were there 

There's a lot more work to get the template and modifications updated, and then figure out which extensions to migrate and which to leave behind.

BUT now that it is 1.9.3 to 2.1.2 I am having to diff my configs with the distributed ones to find changes. They are still evolving it.

Comment: yes, many things are still under development. there are lot to do with migration. magento provides code migration too https://github.com/magento/code-migration. this may help to migrate code  too

Comment: error not resolved..